# Android- modifying drag shadow without changing the drag-start view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I would like to create a custom drag shadow that is different from the view being dragged (actually it is a modified version of the view being dragged).

I can pass a view to the `View.DragShadowBuilder` constructor like so:

```
View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(myView);
```

Problem is any changes I make to `myView` also affects the View being dragged (and this is because Views cannot be cloned). [How do I clone a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159211/how-do-i-clone-a-view)

Alternatively I can extend the View.DragShadowBuilder and draw my custom view  with a Bitmap in the provided `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. But I am having trouble generating a shadow at all in the first place (I am assuming this is a valid approach).

Conversely is it possible to make a custom drag shadow at all from a View attached to the screen ? Any pointers or a solution would be most helpful.

My searches so far haven't yielded any useful results:
[How to create a custom drag shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274384/how-to-create-a-custom-drag-shadow)
[How to show custom DragShadow instead of ListViewFragment row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462691/how-to-show-custom-dragshadow-instead-of-listviewfragment-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering own question. The argument passed to `View.DragShadowBuilder(View view)` needs to be visible (and attached to a suitable layout container). An inflated view from xml or a dynamically created view that is not attached to any ViewGroup / View does not generate any drag shadow.

The key here is to extend the  `View.DragShadowBuilder` class and override the `onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)` method

```
@Override
onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
    final View view = mView.get();

    /* give drag shadow a blue background, this also changes the drag-start view
    attached to the screen */
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    view.draw(canvas);

    /* bring the drag-start view back to its original state (does not affect drag-shadow) */
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

If your requirement is to change the drag shadow so that it appears different from the `drag-start` view attached to the screen, modify the view before you call the `view.draw(canvas)` and bring it back to its original state after the `view.draw(canvas)` method.

This gets the job done, but comes across as a hack. To summarize the key here is to manipulate the view before the `draw(canvas)` method and reset it to its original state after the same method. Hope this was useful.

Answer (score -1):

[View.updateDragShadow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#updateDragShadow(android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder)) is exposed for this, SDK version >= 24.
I guess your solution is better because it's much more flexible.